# Non-intrusive stored-procedure auditing on Orace 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, audit

I'm working in a environment where there are a large variety of legacy client programs.  I'm trying to get an idea of which programs use what stored procedures.  Is there a way to audit access to a stored procedure without having to modify said procedure?  I could figure what each procedure accesses and add audit triggers for the underlying objects, but there are a lot of procedures to examine.  Identification of DB user and ideally hostname would be sufficient.   I took a peek at the FGA package, but couldn't see how to apply it to procedures.

Disclaimer: I'm not a DBA, so my terminology may be imprecise.  Apologies in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [AUDIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm#i2059073) command? There is a provision in the command to audit stored procedures:

AUDIT ALL ON schema.procedure;

You will, of course, need to enable auditing on your database.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see AUDIT, but I didn't fully get the meaning of
    ON *schema_object_clause*